# Render of Smoke/Fire shows nothing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, physics, cache

I am doing the Blenderguru tutorial on Making Fire. After the initial setup he does a render and so did I ....

[image]

Probably I did something silly but I cannot find it. I already did delete the circle  and domain and recreated these but nothing. What is my mistake 
?

[image]

Comment: Are you using GPU? Is the material made correctly?

Comment: I am doing it on CPU, I know that GPU does not work

Comment: Works. Go to the first frame and press Alt+A or bake it before, see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5fgk2.png

Comment: @poor Ctrl + A gives apply location ?

Comment: It previews and render correctly http://i.stack.imgur.com/rNOWn.png Consider changing the background to be darker or add a back light to light the smoke http://i.stack.imgur.com/03z6i.png

Comment: your are all right !! my humble excuses (I was pushing on the render button and I did not realise that I should play an animation).

Comment: by the way, this i.stack.imgur.com ...how can you upload images there ?

Comment: @JanScherders  See [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/985/images-in-comments).  (You've probably already figured this out, but he said **Alt** + A, which plays the animation; **Ctrl** + A applies transforms.)  You seem to be at frame 0 where there is no smoke emitted yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can render a smoke simulation you need to **run the simulation once**.

To do that go to the **first frame** and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (or the play animation button on the timeline)

[image]

Pay attention to the gray bar being created at the bottom of the time line, it will show you the frames that have been cached.

So the key thing to learn is that the information for most simulations (smoke, physics, particles, etc) has to be created and cached first. Otherwise blender has no information to be rendered.

Also, any changes made in the simulation will require that you re-cache the whole thing.

Comment: Now I understand it !!

Comment: by the way, If you re-cache does Blender simple overwrite the previous cache or do you have to remove the old cache before you play the animation again ?

Comment: @JanScherders just go back to the first frame of the simulation and press Alt+A again. Blender will re-create the simulation.