# Why wont smoke appear?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have problems with my quick smoke......i applied quick some to that cube,and started my anim,but i see nothing in viewport,please help me.
[image]

Comment: Does [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47480/3710) help? Also see: https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/smoke/introduction.html

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45001/2843

Comment: i tried every of them...but my smoke is still not visible in viewport